# How can I use my custom input method in botium?

Tags: automation, chatbot

I have developed my custom chatbot. I have my own custom response. So How can I Implement it using botium for checking conversation and using webdriver io.

Comment: Please be more specific, I don't get what you want to do or what you want to know.

Comment: We have developed custom chatbot in which for some types of question only user need to type in text box and click on the send button. e.g. for nmae and contact no. There some other question type in which we provide cards with button or image or link or only button. Or we are having some other controls like calender. For this kind of inputs how can i implement botium using webdriver io and also how can implement custom asserters. Which function i need to change in botium ?

Answer (score 0):

The [**Botium Webdriver Connector**](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio) is the bridge between Selenium and Botium. It provides the framework to automate conversations in chatbot widgets integrated into a website. As such, it makes some reasonable assumptions on the DOM/HTML strucutre of the chatbot widget:
* There is some kind of input box for sending text to the chatbot
* There is a clearly identifieable output element where the chatbot responses are rendered
* Certain HTML elements are identified as clickable buttons ("button", "a href")

All of those assumptions can be changed with Botium capabilities, or for deeper changes by overriding Javascript functions responsible for a special Selenium task (for example, converting the chatbot output to a Botium object, or to do a click on a special kind of button, ...). In the respository above you can find developer documentation and sample code for doing this.

So this is the answer to the first part of your question.

For the second part, how to write custom asserters, you can find an introduction in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24477705/Developing+Custom+Asserters).

*One more hint: When testing a chatbot, doing it on UI level as with Selenium and the Botium Webdriver connector should only be a small part of the testing strategy. Testing on UI level usually is slow and flaky. If there is a chatbot widget on a website, there is most likely some kind of API in the backend, which should be used for doing testing an API level - for example with the [Generic HTTP(S)/JSON connector](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector).*:

Comment: we are using not using socketio, I dont think, we can use HTTP/JSON connector . another way to check in backend?

Comment: There are lots of Botium connectors for all important chatbot technologies available (https://github.com/codeforequity-at?tab=repositories). And you can even build your own connector (https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/38502401/Writing+own+connector).

Comment: If I write custom input method, then how can setup for botium capabilities?

Comment: There are two parts: you will have to register your custom input method for BotiumScript, and you will have to adapt the connector. Maybe let's continue the discussion on another channel. We recently created a Discord channel for developers, please contact us on our website to get access.

Comment: could you please mention the site navigation where I can contact

Comment: I have submitted the request for access. Please approve

Comment: I have submitted the support request on above website. Still didnt get any revert. Could you please check and grant me access